# On which site should I ask how to find publishing websites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to write a book version of the *[Naruto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto)* manga. But I don't know where I can post it. I want to find a website where I can publish my writing so everyone can read it. Where should I ask this question?

Answer (score 5):

For your specific genre you may try to ask your question at [SE Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/).

At a first glance it seems to ask about website resources is OK there.

Alternatively [SE Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com) seems also to be OK.

In any case show some research efforts you've done yourself so far.

Comment: Ok I'll try this